# Donation/Contribution Page Best Practices

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, contribution-page, simple-donate-form

Are there examples of Donation/Contribution Pages that have been created with CiviCRM or Drupal Web Form that you think work well?

Are there advantages of creating it with CiviCRM or Drupal Web Forms?

Also are there ways to get it to work, so it uses the organization's url?
name.org/donate?

Thank you.

Comment: i don't think this question suits SE very well since it is asking for 'opinion' ie "that you think work well". There are many, many pages of CiviCRM contribution forms out there. Can you edit your question to be more specific about what you are wanting as the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

After going back and forth from CiviCRM forms to Drupal Webforms for contribution forms, I find that the way to go for Contribution pages is CiviCRM forms.

A couple of issues that come to mind with Drupal webforms as a contribution form was:
1) The payment instrument was always set to "Check" even though they pay with Credit Card.
2) The Contribution thank you letters weren't sending out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In short, CiviCRM-Contribution pages work well if you can stick to the default workflow and functions and if your requirements regarding layout and functionality are not too fancy. Examples:

- You can decide which information to ask from donors for each donation page but you for example not easily create a activity at the time the form is sent
- You cannot change layout and style of the form easily and there is usually a three-step form (data entry page - confirmation page, thank you page)
- Conditional forms are not easy to implement with CiviCRM contribution pages
- Changing content and layout of the automated confirmation mail can be a pain

On the plus side, those forms are really easy to set up and most CiviCRM payment processors should work out of the box.

With Drupal webform integration you can do all kind of fancy stuff with your forms, including adding other pages, conditional fields, massively changing the layout, decide on the url you want to use, record other data whne the form is filled out etc.

The downside is that you will need more ressoruces and technical expertise to set up, and you have to test your custom forms properly. Creating the forms and integrating them with the website can be a bit more complex for inexperienced users too. Finally, there range of available payment processors is more limited.

So it really depends on the project planned. There is also the option to build a completely separate form and connect it to CiviCRM via the API which gives you utmost flexibility but is even more complex to set up than a webform.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Is there a reason why the email field appears below the donation amounts?

For example, on this page: http://migrantjustice.net/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1  

Is there a way to group the email field with the person's contact information?

Comment: Better to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

A third approach that could be developed is through the CiviCRM Entity module which Fuzion and Skvare have put a lot of effort in to. Mark Hanna is outlining future developments for the module in this [blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/jackrabbithanna/civicrm-entity-upcoming-and-future-development) which could include Contribution forms and the discussion is occurring [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2676756).